# SCP command not working in Crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron, scp, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to write a cronjob using scp.But scp is not working correctly.

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/bin/bash:/usr/bin/ssh:/usr/bin/scp
scp -i pi@ipadress:/home/pi/filename /home/flash/mylog.log
```

scp command works fine when I run it from terminal without password.My log file has nothing in it(it is blank).

How should I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Q1:** *how do you authenticate?* **A1:** *Using private key.* **Q2:** *Where is this key stored?*

Comment: I generated key using ssh keygen and placed it in .ssh/authentication directory.

Comment: That does not sound right.

Comment: I was able to login without password after this. Also when run the script manually or using "at" command it works fine.

Comment: and where is the private key stored? Is it passphrase protected? The cronjob runs under which user?

Comment: It is in default directory on my local machine and in .ssh/authorized_key on remote machine. It is passphrase protected and crown job is running under normal user not under root user.

Comment: And how do you provide the passphrase to the `scp`?

Comment: It doesn't ask for passphrase when I run the Scp script. I just put the passphrase while login in to remote machine for first time.

Comment: Then it is stored in your `ssh-agent` in your session. It is not visible from the `crontab`. It is not dependent on your session. So you need a way to specify the passphrase or create a key without passphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-i` switch has its meaning. It requires the path to your key:

```
sshpass -p passphrase scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa pi@ipadress:/home/pi/filename /home/flash/mylog.log
```

or leave it out completely, if it is in the default location:

```
sshpass -p passphrase scp pi@ipadress:/home/pi/filename /home/flash/mylog.log
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.